# Can't get SharedPreferences with activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Sorry for my bad English.
 
On my application, I save token (it's a web app) in shared preferences. In first activity I do this:

```
(token = 123)
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor ed = sp.edit();
ed.putString("token", Main.getToken()); 
ed.commit();
Log.d("Recieved token: ", sp.getString("token", "null")); // Recieved token: 123
```

As you see, shared prefs are saved. 
I have another activity, which may be called from browser to share link. 
Code:

```
sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Log.d("Token recieved: ", sp.getString("token", "null")); // null
```

But on another activity shared prefs return null. 
What can I do?

Comment: use getSharedPreferences()

Comment: Thank you! That's the right answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To explain the reason why getPreferences() didn't work for you:

When you call getPreferences() without specifying a Shared Preferences name, it returns a Shared Preference using the calling Activity's class name as the Shared Preference name. That's why you are getting null in your other activity - it's actually a different Shared Preference set that you are referring to.

Use getSharedPreferences instead, using whatever preferences name you like:

```
getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

That will then be available throughout your application. However using getPreferences() is suitable where you don't need to refer to the data stored outside of a particular Activity.

Comment: In what situations I should use getPreferences()?

Comment: Where the preferences data that you are storing is only needed by that individual Activity. It is good practice to make the scope of data only as wide as it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

use like following,,

```
SharedPreferences mAppSettings = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = mAppSettings.edit();
        prefEditor.putString(""token, "");
        prefEditor.commit();
```

for retrieving,,,

```
final SharedPreferences mAppSettings1 = getSharedPreferences(
                "SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
             String token= mAppSettings1.getString("token", "");
```